# Знаки препинания при обрыве фразы в диалоге

Tags: пунктуация, диалог

Существует диалог. Во время произнесения фразы происходит что-то внезапное.

— Привет. Давно тебя не видел.
— Здорова. А что ты тут дела- - договорить я не успел.

Собственно, вопрос в том, что именно должно быть здесь:

> дела- - договорить я не успел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос:

*— Привет. Давно тебя не видел.

— Здорова. А что ты тут дела- - договорить я не успел.*

Ответ:
**1**. При "обрыве" фразы ставится троеточие и тире.
**2.** "Здорова" (ж. р.) и "договорить не успел" (м. р.) — не согласуются по роду.

Есть два варианта:

*— Привет. Давно тебя не видел.

— **Здоров**. А что ты тут дела... — договорить я **не успел**.*

Или:
*— Привет. Давно тебя не видел.

— **Здорова**. А что ты тут дела... — договорить я  **не успела**.*

[**Знаки при прямой речи, пар.196**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/164-znapr)

**Дополнение**
Или:
— Привет. Давно тебя не видел.
— Здорово. А что ты тут дела... — договорить я не успел.

Comment: Скорее весего, там приветствие: "ЗдорОво!"

Comment: Да, наверное. Сейчас добавлю (автор-то молчит).

Comment: Автор очень благодарен за ответ. Собственно, дело было не в обращении (как правильно догадался М_Г, это было приветствие, с ударением на вторую О), а в том, какие знаки нужно было использовать.

Большое мерси за ответ.